# Migrating SQL Server Outer Apply Query to Snowflake query

Tags: sql, date, sql-order-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-limit

Working on migrating to Snowflake from SQL Server. Stuck at below query. Couldn't find anything equivalent in Snowflake.
For every row in outer query we go in inner query to get top datekey which is smaller than datekey in outer query.

```
    select a.datekey , a.userid, a.transactionid
    ,cast( cast(b.datekey as varchar(8)) as date) priorone
    from tableA a
    outer apply (select top 1 b.datekey
                  from tableA b where a.userid = b.userid
                  and b.transactionid < a.transactionid and b.datekey < a.datekey
    order by b.transactionid desc) as b
```

Tried suggested answer as below:

```
create or replace table tableA
   (datekey date , userid int ,transactionid int)
   insert into tableA
   values('2020-06-01',1,101),('2020-06-02',1,102),('2020-06-02',1,103),('2020-06-01',2,104),('2020-06-02',2,105)
    select 
    a.datekey, 
    a.userid, 
    a.transactionid
    ,(
        select b.datekey
        from tableA b 
        where 
            a.userid = b.userid
            and b.transactionid < a.transactionid 
            and b.datekey < a.datekey
        order by b.transactionid desc
        limit 1
    ) priorone
from tableA a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the LEAD() function in Snowflake.  It'll save you the subquery or join altogether:

```
select 
    datekey, 
    userid, 
    transactionid,
    lead(datekey) over (partition by userid order by datekey desc) as priorone
from tableA;
```

This gets the next record for the userid based on a descending order of datekey.

You could also use LAG() and get do the sort the opposite way:

```
select 
    datekey, 
    userid, 
    transactionid,
    lag(datekey) over (partition by userid order by datekey asc) as priorone
from tableA;
```

Answer (score 1):

lead/lag is no substitute for slq server outer apply

outer apply lets you do a top 1, which is the only reason I have ever used it - super handy.  You cannot do a top 1 in a CTE, because a CTE is evaluated first before its joined to.  So, an outer apply is the only solution I can see.  Too bad its not in snowflake

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting one column from the outer join, so you could rephrase the code as a straight correlated subquery.

Snowflake does not support `top`, but it has the same functionality implemented with `limit`.

Finally, it seems like you want to remove the time potion of `datekey`: you can use `date()` for this.

```
select 
    a.datekey, 
    a.userid, 
    a.transactionid
    (
        select date(b.datekey)
        from tableA b 
        where 
            a.userid = b.userid
            and b.transactionid < a.transactionid 
            and b.datekey < a.datekey
        order by b.transactionid desc
        limit 1
    ) priorone
from tableA a
```

Comment: Don't think Snowflake allow this type of subquery. Getting below error 
`SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated`

Comment: @user1579411 - @GMB's query compiles and runs on a simple create schema `create table tableA (datekey date, userid integer, transactionid integer)`. You're likely getting an error due to the real schema/query being different - perhaps update your post to add further specifics?

Comment: I tried with simple schema but it doesn't work for me still. Getting same subquery error. Started to work in Snowflake recently and looking into documentation it doesn't look like co-related subqueries are supported yet. added simple schema and test query in question.

Comment: Snowflake does support TOP now.